# Change label text in Gutenberg's built in excerpt panel

Tags: block-editor, excerpt

The excerpt panel in the Gutenberg block editor has the label text "Write an excerpt (optional)"

How can this text be edited? Specifically I want to remove "(optional)".

I've attempted to target the label with JS, but neither of the below work (just see an empty collection in the console). If I run `document.getElementsByClassName('e1puf3u2')` in the console, I get back the label element.

```js
wp.domReady(() => {
  let labels = document.getElementsByClassName('e1puf3u2');
  console.log(labels);
});


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let labels = document.getElementsByClassName('e1puf3u2');
  console.log(labels);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That label is a translatable text and its translation is retrieved using `wp.i18n.__()`, so you can change the text like you could in PHP via the [`gettext` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/), except that in JS/Gutenberg, you'd use [`i18n.gettext`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/i18n-filters/).

Working example:

```js
// Define our filter callback.
function myPluginGettextFilter( translation, text, domain ) {
    if ( text === 'Write an excerpt (optional)' ) {
        return 'Write an excerpt';
    }

    return translation;
}

// Adding the filter
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'i18n.gettext',
    'my-plugin/override-write-an-excerpt-label',
    myPluginGettextFilter
);
```

And another way to change the text, without using hooks, is by using [`wp.i18n.setLocaleData()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-i18n/#setlocaledata) like so:

```js
wp.i18n.setLocaleData({
    'Write an excerpt (optional)': [
        'Write an excerpt'
    ]
});
/* The format is:
wp.i18n.setLocaleData({
    '<original text>': [
        '<singular translation>',
        '<plural translation>'
    ]
});

// but just pass one translation (one array item) if there are no plural
// translation available, or if both singular and plural translations are
// identical
*/
```

And remember to load the script's dependency, i.e. `wp-hooks` for the 1st example, and `wp-i18n` for the 2nd example.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks @SallyCJ